# Why the vue-lang do not work with filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I using [vue-lang](https://github.com/kvdmolen/vue-lang). It works, but not completely

**ISSUE**

in the JSON file there is an example of:

```
"messages": "You have {0} {1} messages"
```

and then this code as a filter

```
<p>{{$lang.messages | replace countmsg 'new'}}</p>
```

But when I do it by example so there is an error here

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: replace countmsg 'new'
```

**MY FILES**

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Lang from 'vue-lang'

const locales = {
  'cs': require('./lang/cs.json')
}

Vue.use(Lang, {lang: 'cs', locales: locales})
```

lang/cs.json

```
{
  "messages": "You have {0} {1} messages"
}
```

views/login.vue

```
<template>
  <p>{{$lang.messages | replace countmsg 'new'}}</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data: function() {
    return {
      countmsg: 5
    }
 }
</script>
```

**Still does not work. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular library but the usual way to use a filter like this would be:

```html
{{ $lang.messages | replace(countmsg, 'new') }}
```

The documentation for that filter appears to be 3 years old so it may be out of date. The syntax for calling filters was changed some time ago: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filter-Argument-Syntax-changed

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Comment: I tried a lot of things, spent hours at that time, and nothing at all. I need help with that.

Comment: @TheCzechTayen I believe that's because `$lang.messages` is `undefined` and the filter is now being called correctly. I suggest adding `{{ $lang }}` to your template to check whether `$lang` is being populated correctly.

Comment: Strange, it just started working out of nowhere. Thanks for the help!